# Building Angular project error "Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'"

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

I'm trying to build --prod my angular project and it keeps giving me this error

> Failed to compile.

```
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:73:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

73 interface IteratorResult<T> { }
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6
    41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts:41:6 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'IteratorResult'.

41 type IteratorResult<T, TReturn = any> = IteratorYieldResult<T> | IteratorReturnResult<TReturn>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:73:11
    73 interface IteratorResult<T> { }
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'IteratorResult' was also declared here.
```

I tried to install node modules again but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Try `npm install --save-dev @types/node` and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `skipLibCheck: true` to your `tsconfig.json` file. This prevents type checking the declaration files so you should not have the issue anymore. Here is also a [link to the description in the documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck).

Possibly also upgrading some of the type definitions as suggested in the comment could help maybe you are using very old versions or you have duplicate references.

Comment: I had trouble using Angular WebWorkers with `localize` and this solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I get the `TS2300: Duplicate identifier` error when compiling my main project for the following reason:

In the `my-custom-library.module.ts`, I accidentally entered the path of the component causing the error with the **wrong case**.

```
import { InputPasswordComponent } from './components/input-Password/input-Password.component';
```

instead of

```
import { InputPasswordComponent } from './components/input-password/input-password.component';
```

This is confusing because no error is thrown while compiling the custom library. (`ng build --prod`).

Obviously, the `skipLibCheck: true` solution does not work in this particular case.

Comment: That was my problem too, I messed up the camelcasing in my component template and styleUrls.

skipLibCheck is not a solution because it does not fix the problem, it just ignore it.
Which can have consequences in the future.